# How to pick last two days of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have sample table data

```
ID  name      St_dt      points
1   Mohan   2017-07-10      20
1   Mohan   2017-07-10      25
1   Mohan   2017-07-07      30
```

when I'm trying to pick last two days

**script** :

```
select * from table 
Where St_dt >= Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
```

how can i pick exactly last two days means different dates by above script I'm not getting exact result .
Below result I need

**output** :

```
ID  name      St_dt     points
1   Mohan   2017-07-10   20
1   Mohan   2017-07-07   30
```

Comment: 2017-07-07 how can be an output ? What is your `select Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE)` ,is your computer time correct ?

Comment: The output above is script result ? or result that what you want ?

Comment: with my script I'm getting wrong result I need output which I posted @gencklavyeler

Comment: ok , last question : why  you need  `1   Mohan   2017-07-10      20 ` instead of  `1   Mohan   2017-07-10      25`

Comment: @gencklavyeler multiple records on same day is not required need to pick only single record on single day using row_number we can achieve but any other way rather than that way

Comment: If it doesn't matter if it's showing 20 or 25 points, then why is points included in your output?

Comment: it is sample data if it in real time points and everything need to take care @Peter

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` can get you one row per each date, and then you simply select last two from that result set

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM 
( 
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY St_dt ORDER BY ID) as RN 
   FROM table  
) x 
WHERE x.RN =1
ORDER BY St_dt DESC
```

Comment: any possibility to achieve in Date functions

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct in a subquery, then take top 2 desc. User outer apply to get the other fields

```
select top 2 a.*
from
    (select distinct St_dt
    from table) c
outer apply (select top 1 * from table where St_dt = c.St_dt) a
order by St_dt desc
```